# Ajax not to refresh remodal popup after submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can we try not to refresh popup keeping open after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: use ajax for form submit

Comment: how can we find the way for using ajax. Please show the code, if you know.

Comment: More accurate question = more accurate answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Answer (score 0):

If you submit form the page will be reload and modal will disappear.

If you use ajax  to send data and get response you will be able to verify response and continue your work on same page.